# fatal error in sql command executing in asp.net class file

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to get some data from table. This query runs fine with **mysql** but while executing in **asp.net c#** class files it throws exception:
Fatal error in sql query.. 
Inner Exception @c is not defined..

```
string sqlQuery = "SET @c:=0;
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TimeStamp, FwdHr, W , @c:=@c+1 as counter
  FROM Meter_Data WHERE TimeStamp >= @fromTime AND TimeStamp <= @toTime
  AND MeterID = @meterID" + " AND DeviceID = @deviceID) as tmp
WHERE counter % 20 =1 ORDER BY TimeStamp";
```

How to define that `@c` then?? as it was running fine in **SQL server**

Answer (score 0):

What you are performing is not a single query, but multiple statements.

`@c` that you set at the start is also the same format that is used for parametrized queries.

c# searches for `@c` in the list of parameters you send, and since this is not found you get an error.

You would be better of writing a routine in mysql that takes your parameters and returns the results. The variable `@c` would be internal to the routine.

Comment: what if i pass @c as outside parameter from c# var?

Comment: You could set it to `0` as a parameter, but I am guessing mysql would not treat that as an internal parameter and update it for every row. No harm giving it a try.

Comment: yes thats the issue. is there some other way of declaring variable or any other query for similar results without variables? @nunepascal

Comment: Writing routines in mysql is very simple. Fits your needs very well. Why not do that?

Comment: If you have written a stored procedure in SQL Server, its the same. Just a few lines of code, and very simple I should say.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a parameter inside you query, in SQL its ok in c#, you dont declare the parameters inside the queries
you only pass them to it

Check out this site for an example ([site](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter))

And better yet, create a stored procedure and call it instead of writing the query in your code

This is better because it will be pre-compiled, and sends less data to the server

Otherwise, each time you send the query to the server it will be re-evaluated and them compiled again

Comment: i have not worked with stored procedures. can you help? also these parameters slow down query. @simsim

Comment: what is the database that you are using ?

Comment: Aha, mysql, just noticed...Sorry, I'm not very familiar with mysql

Comment: i am using MySQL.. is there any alternative for having same results without using variables for this query?

Comment: by looking at your query, you can rank your data instead of using the @c parameter as a counter, this way you dont need the first parameter **google how this can be done in mysql**, plus, constructing your query in a string concatenated together with the values of the parameters instead of using the parameters will work, but this will put you under the risk on sql injections, and not recommended

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with simple query bcz time stamp is int and it increments like - 1902020222, 1902020223,...

```
 string sqlQuery = "SELECT TimeStamp, FwdHr, W FROM Meter_Data WHERE TimeStamp >= @fromTime AND TimeStamp <= @toTime AND MeterID = @meterID" +
                        " AND DeviceID = @deviceID AND TimeStamp%20 = 0 ORDER BY TimeStamp;";
```